# codepen: jQuery .css() edit when scrolldown past anchor, vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

codepen http://codepen.io/mathiasvanderbrempt/pen/mJjjrx

I need to figure out why this jquery isn't working...

I want to make the `.navigationfx` drop down (top = 0px) when its scrolltop() reaches the first section (should I add a class or id?). Accordingly, I want to make it move up (top = -30px) when it scrolls back up past it.

```
  $(function(){
  //last scroll will always save the current scroll position value
  var CurrentScroll = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
      var NextScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (NextScroll > CurrentScroll){
         //codes related to down-ward scrolling here
                if    ($(window).scrollTop() > $('section').scrollTop())
              {
                $('navigationfx').css('top', '0px')
              }
              else {
                $('navigationfx').css('top', '-100px')
              }
      }
      else {
         //codes related to upward-scrolling here
                if ($(window).scrollTop() < $('section').scrollTop())
              {
                $('navigationfx').css('top', '-100px')
              }
              else {
                $('navigationfx').css('top', '0px')
              }
      }
      //Updates current scroll position
      CurrentScroll = NextScroll;
  });
});
```

css

```
  .navigationfx {
  visibility: ;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddedf
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

You select the first section form the matched set as:

```
$('section').first();
```

Since, the section has no scroll, you would have to use the offset top as:

```
$('section').first().offset().top;
```

Do not scan the DOM over and over for the same element. Store a reference and use it as you need as:

```
var $nav = $(".navigationfx");
var $firstSection = $('section').first();
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but, here is [your pen updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpBGeG)

P.S. It's okay to use `.css()` to add/update `top` for this specific scenario and doesn't have to be add/remove a class.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `$('section').scrollTop()` permanently equal `0`.

Change it to `$("section").offset().top`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPpeKv

Comment: How is this an answer? I defines the problem, but doesn't give a solution.

Comment: @LinkinTED It answers the question of why there is no change in the positioning unit - because the `if` condition is never satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

When you log `$('section').scrollTop()` to the console, you'll see that it always returns zero. Instead, use `$('section').offset().top`.

You are also missing a `.` in the navigationfx selector.

```
$(function(){
    //last scroll will always save the current scroll position value
    var CurrentScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var NextScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (NextScroll > CurrentScroll){
            //codes related to down-ward scrolling here
            if($(window).scrollTop() > $('section').offset().top)
            {
                $('.navigationfx').css('top', '0px')
            }
            else {
                $('.navigationfx').css('top', '-100px')
            }
        }
        else {
            //codes related to upward-scrolling here
            if($(window).scrollTop() < $('section').offset().top)
            {
                $('.navigationfx').css('top', '-100px')
            }
            else {
                $('.navigationfx').css('top', '0px')
            }
        }
        //Updates current scroll position
        CurrentScroll = NextScroll;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('navigationfx') => $('.navigationfx')
```

and I think all this code can be shorten to that:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
            var offset = $(window).scrollTop() > $('section').offset().top?'0px':'-100px';
            $('.navigationfx').css('top', offset);
    });
    $(window).scroll();
});
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXjJLG